# Forced https redirects in .htaccess result in /admin being redirected to /

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I have SSL certificates all in place for my website and its associated alias domains.

I've inherited a Laravel framework - backed up by a database - which dictates what page is rendered on different domains. Fairly standard, I hope.

Forcing redirects on I'm forcing redirects for my primary domain within .htaccess using:

```
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

All fine and dandy - this works perfectly. However, when accessing https://www.mywebsite.co.uk/admin this redirect stops access and redirects to https://www.mywebsite.co.uk

I've never come across this behaviour before if I'm being honest, so any advise would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/\1 [L,R=301]
```

This will capture your page and append page to https://xxxxxxx/

Instead of the "RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off" You can also place the rewrite rule in a that listen http only (  ) and not the general config.

Also you will loose the POST that will became a GET and body parameter. For instance, if you come from a form like

```
<form method="POST" action="http://xxxxxx">
```

your server will detect it is http so will send a redirect to https.  The browser will send back the https:// but with a GET. Also, the redirect remove the body of the query, so if there was parameter in there (or json) the redirect will remove that.

Comment: For example, what does this do...and do I use this in place of what I have or instead of...? Etc thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not accept this answer - error returned was "too many redirects".

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off need to be uncommented to be able to detect if it is http or https.

Comment: @wargre Hmmm, this seems to redirect the main site page to /page.